# PHP Curl to echosign api outputting raw data

Tags: php, codeigniter, curl, echosign

This is my code

```
<?php //if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

require_once APPPATH."/libraries/REST_Controller.php";
require_once APPPATH."/libraries/echosign.php";

class Document_management extends Rest_Controller
{
  public function get_access_token_get()
  {    
    $echoSign = new EchoSign();

    $ch = curl_init('https://secure.echosign.com/api/rest/v2/auth/tokens');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($echoSign->echosign_creds));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json'));

    $result = json_decode(curl_exec($ch));    

    curl_close($ch);    

    return $result->accessToken;
  }

  public function get_agreements_get()
  {
    $accessToken = array("Access-Token: ".$this->get_access_token_get());

    $ch = curl_init('https://secure.echosign.com:443/api/rest/v2/agreements');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $accessToken);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true);

    $result = json_decode(curl_exec($ch));

    curl_close($ch);

    $agreements = array(
        "agreementId"   => $result->userAgreementList[0]->agreementId,
        "name"          => $result->userAgreementList[0]->name,
    );    

    return $agreements;
  }

  public function get_form_data_get($headers, $agreements)
  {
    $filepath = APPPATH."files/".$agreements['name']."csv";

    $url = 'https://secure.echosign.com:443/api/rest/v2/agreements/'.$agreements['agreementId'].'/formData';

    $ch = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);    
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, false);    
    //header("Content-type: text/csv");
    //header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".$filepath);

    $result = curl_exec($ch);

    //echo "<pre>"; print_r($result); echo "</pre>"; exit();

    curl_close($ch);

  }

  public function download_file_get()
  {
    $headers = array("Access-Token: ".$this->get_access_token_get());

    $agreements = $this->get_agreements_get();

    $this->get_form_data_get($headers, $agreements);
  }


}

?>
```

The output in the browser just sends the RAW data of the form in this format

```
"completed","email","role","first","last","title","company","agreementId","firstname","lastname" "2014-11-04 15:55:44","abe.taha@gmail.com","SIGNER","Abe","Taha","Web Developer","","2AAABLblqZhDrvBK47mPKPZW-VSAJKDHASFT42ESlPxOjYphH4C0A5_adasdasda6qnFCy2idJ8*","ABE","TAHA"
```

I don't know how to store the stream in a variable / even explode it somehow to store it in a database.

I have tried using php://input or readfile and other options to read the stream but dont understand how to format the data

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are using the EchoSign REST API `GET /agreements/{agreementId}/formData` and want further details on it's output. The above call generates a CSV (comma separated file).

If the call is successful, this return parameter will contain the comma-separated form data values, with each record separated by newlines. The first line will always contain the header values - i.e. the keys for all the columns.

In the case that the key `agreementId` refers to a specific agreement, there will then be another line for each signer of that agreement, with each item in that line being the form value entered by that signer corresponding to the appropriate header.